# Help - Expectations and Ratios

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, ratio, symmetry

I would need your help for a problem I have and I don't know how to solve.

I would like to know whether I could prove that : 
$$E[0.5X/(0.5X+0.25)] = E[0.5(1-X)/(0.5(1-X)+0.25)]$$
knowing that $E[X] = 0.5$ and its distribution is symmetric.

If it makes things easier, I can assume that X follows a normal distribution with a mean of $0.5$.

Would someone knows either how to prove that $$E[0.5X/(0.5X+0.25)] = E[0.5(1-X)/(0.5(1-X)+0.25)]$$ or tell me under which conditions this would be true?

Many many thanks for anyone who will reply.

Comment: I suggest that you start with the definition of the expectation value: $\mathbb{E} = \int dx 0.5x/(0.5 + 0.25) p(x)$, where p(x) is the distribution of x and do the math. I doubt that symmetry $p(x)=p(-x) is sufficient here. More likely $p(x)=p(1-x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the PDF is symmetric around $0.5$, we have $f_X(x)=f_X(1-x)$. Then write the expectation as follows (assume continuous RV for simplicity):
$$\begin{align}E\left[\frac{0.5X}{0.5X+0.25}\right]&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{0.5X}{0.5X+0.25} f_X(x)dx\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{0.5(1-Y)}{0.5(1-Y)+0.25}f_X(1-y)dy\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{0.5(1-Y)}{0.5(1-Y)+0.25}f_X(y)dy\\&=E\left[\frac{0.5(1-X)}{0.5(1-X)+0.25}\right]\end{align}$$

Intuitively, both $X$ and $1-X$ have the same probability mass/density. So, any expectation (if defined) consisting of a variable change between the two will have the same value.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to help me. I should have mentionned that X is a probability, so it is between 0 and 1. Does it change anything? Could I integrate the expressions from 0 to 1 similarly? NB: it is written fX(1-y)dy at the seocnd line, but I should write fX(1-x), is this correct?

Thanks a million times, you saved my day!

Comment: Range doesn't matter, because if your support is in $[0,1]$ range, PDF will be zero outside the range, which will automatically compress the integral range to $[0,1]$. I've just made a variable change to the integration $Y=1-X$, you can made another change in the third line $Y=X$, but it doesn't matter. Just focus on the definition of expectation. The integral variable is not important.

Comment: Gunes, sure but I don't know how to do it (it is the first time I use the website). I will look for how to do it. In any case, many many thanks, it really helped me and it is very generous of you to take time to reply!